# Error 403 (insufficient scopes) for Google Drive API service->files->listFiles()

Tags: php, google-drive-api, http-status-code-403

I am trying to develop an application that will provide synchronization of folders between a Linux filesystem folder and Google Drive.  The problem I have is that I cannot seem to get past a 403 error with the message:

> Request had insufficient authentication scopes

I have success with the Google "Try the API" page [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22corpora%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22includeItemsFromAllDrives%22%3Atrue%2C%22orderBy%22%3A%22name%22%2C%22spaces%22%3A%22drive%22%2C%22supportsAllDrives%22%3Atrue%7D), when I populate these fields/values:

```php
'corpa' => 'user'
'includeFilesFromAllDrives' => true
'supportsAllDrives' => true
'spaces' => 'drive'
```

That returns a list of objects.  But when I try this in PHP, like:

```php
$result = $drv->service->files->listFiles( [
                              'corpa' => 'user'
                            , 'includeFilesFromAllDrives' => true
                            , 'supportsAllDrives' => true
                            , 'spaces' => 'drive'
                                    ]) ;
```

the result is:

```json
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
      "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Insufficient Permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.apps.drive.v3.DriveFiles.List",
          "service": "drive.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

On that page is a comment:

```
Requires one of the following OAuth scopes:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
```

In an effort to get beyond this, I've actually selected *all* of these values (together) when creating the client.  There isn't any apparent objection to my use of the scopes, but still the authorization is rejected.

The code to build the $service object is in a class (DriveStuff), as follows:

```
public function GetService($clientSecretFile = null
                            , $scopes = null
                            , $useKey = false
                            , $debug = false
                            ) {
    if ($this->DEBUG)
        error_log("GetService() called") ;
    $this->loginEpoch = time() ;             // For automatic login before key expiration (hard limit 1 hour)
    if (is_null($this->firstLoginEpoch)) $this->firstLoginEpoch = $this->loginEpoch ;
    $this->loginExpires = time() + (60 * 60) ; // Expires in 60 minutes
    $this->loginCount++ ;
    $pageFile = $this->pathToScript ;
    if ($useKey) { // Using API KEY rather than login credentials
        $client = new Google_Client() ;
        $client->setApplicationName('gDrive stuff');
        $client->setDeveloperKey($this->apiKey) ;
        }
    else { // Standard login to Client services
        if (is_null($clientSecretFile))
            $clientSecretFile = $this->clientFileJSON ;
        if (is_null($clientSecretFile)) {
            $clientSecretFile = $this->GetYouTubeControlParameter("CLIENT_SECRET_FILE", $pageFile) ;
            $this->clientFileJSON = $clientSecretFile ;
            }
        if (is_null($scopes))
            $scopes = $this->scopes ;
        if (is_null($scopes)) {
            $scopes = $this->GetYouTubeControlParameter("SCOPES", $pageFile) ;
            $this->scopes = $scopes ;
            }
        if (is_string($scopes))
            if (strstr($scopes, ',') > 0)
                $scopes = explode(',', $scopes) ;
            else
                $scopes = [ $scopes ] ;
        if ( ! in_array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', $scopes))
            $scopes[] = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' ; // Add this service
        $this->scopes = $scopes ;

        $client = $this->GetAuth($clientSecretFile, $scopes) ;
        if ($debug) {
            foreach ($client->getScopes() AS $scope)
                error_log('Requesed scope: ' . $scope) ;
            }
        }
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client) ;
    $this->service = $service ;
    $this->reLogInFile = $clientSecretFile ; // For automatic login before key expiration (hard limit 1 hour)
    $this->reLogInScopes = $scopes ;         // For automatic login before key expiration (hard limit 1 hour)
    $this->reLogInUseKey = $useKey ;         // For automatic login before key expiration (hard limit 1 hour)
    return $this->service ;
    }
```

The program code at this point is fairly straighrforward:

```
require_once('DriveRelated/DriveStuff.php') ;

$drv = new DriveStuff($lov, false) ; // True sets debug mode
$service = $drv->GetService(null
                            , [   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
                                , 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata'
                                , 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
                                , 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata'
                                , 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
                                , 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly'
                                , 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
                                  ]
                            , false, true) ;
$result = $drv->service->files->listFiles( [ 'pageSize' => 3000 ],
                                [
                                  'corpa' => 'user'
                                , 'includeFilesFromAllDrives' => true
                                , 'supportsAllDrives' => true
                                , 'spaces' => 'drive'
                                        ]) ;
```

... and the log file contains:

```
[03-Aug-2023 20:28:03 America/New_York] Requesed scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
[03-Aug-2023 20:28:03 America/New_York] Requesed scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
[03-Aug-2023 20:28:03 America/New_York] Requesed scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
[03-Aug-2023 20:28:03 America/New_York] Requesed scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata
[03-Aug-2023 20:28:03 America/New_York] Requesed scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly
[03-Aug-2023 20:28:03 America/New_York] Requesed scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly
[03-Aug-2023 20:28:03 America/New_York] Requesed scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly]
[03-Aug-2023 20:28:05 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Insufficient Permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.apps.drive.v3.DriveFiles.List",
          "service": "drive.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
 in /www/cgi-bin/YouTubeRelated/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php:134
Stack trace:
#0 /www/cgi-bin/YouTubeRelated/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php(107): Google\Http\REST::decodeHttpResponse()
#1 [internal function]: Google\Http\REST::doExecute()
#2 /www/cgi-bin/YouTubeRelated/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Task/Runner.php(187): call_user_func_array()
#3 /www/cgi-bin/YouTubeRelated/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php(66): Google\Task\Runner->run()
#4 /www/cgi-bin/YouTubeRelated/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Client.php(922): Google\Http\REST::execute()
#5 /www/cgi-bin/YouTubeRelated/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Service/Resource.php(238): Google\Client->execute()
#6 /www/cgi-bin/YouTubeRelated/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Drive/Resource/Files.php(258): Google\Service\Resource->call()
#7 /www/htdocs/gdrive/gdrive-test.php(30): Google\Service\Drive\Resource\Files->listFiles()
#8 {main}
  thrown in /www/cgi-bin/YouTubeRelated/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php on line 134
```

By the way, I have tried a few subsets of the scopes (such as all readonly scopes, all-except-readonly, and so on), without any change in the result.

I have good, and rather extensive, experience with the YouTube API, so I am certain this will be overcome.  Now I'm looking for the missing piece so I can proceed beyond this beginner stage with Google Drive.

Notice that the word 'requested' is misspelled, but this is only a cosmetic issue.

**EDIT** As requested, here is the authorizaion code:

```
/**
 * Get access code from Database or from Google 
 * @param null|string %clientSecreFile json file from GoogleDegeloper's Console project export
 * @param null|string|array $scopes the requested scope(s).  If not specified, these will e retrieved from preferences
 * @param string $appName value to place into client application name ($client->SetApplicationName())
 * @return mixed client object
*/
public function GetAuth($clientSecretFile
                        , $scopes
                        , $appName = 'Google Drive stuff'
                        ) {
    $this->clientSecretFile = $clientSecretFile ;
    if ($this->DEBUG)
        error_log("GetAuth() called") ;
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client_json = json_decode(file_get_contents($clientSecretFile), true) ;

    // For Desktop apps, $client_json top will be 'installed'; for Weh apps, this is 'weh'....

    if (count($client_json) == 1)                       // Key may be 'web' or 'installed'
        $topKey = implode(array_keys($client_json)) ;
    else
        $topKey = 'installed' ;
    $clientId = $client_json[$topKey]['client_id'] ;
    $clientSecret = $client_json[$topKey]['client_secret'] ;
    $client->setApplicationName($appName);
    if ( is_string($scopes))
        $scopes = [ $scopes ] ;
    $client->setScopes($scopes);
    $authHistoyRow['authConfig'] = json_encode($client_json) ;
    $client->setAuthConfig($client_json) ;
    $accessType = 'offline' ;
    $client->setAccessType($accessType);
    $this->GetClientFromDB($clientId        // Handles inserttion of new Client information if necessary; returns as much information as we have otherwise
                        , $clientSecret
                        , $scope            // Values below here (including this value) are passed by reference, and are updated by GetClientFromDB()
                        , $accessToken      // Updated by GetClientFromDB()
                        , $tokenType        // Updated by GetClientFromDB()
                        , $refreshToken     // Updated by GetClientFromDB()
                        , $expires          // Updated by GetClientFromDB()
                        , $created          // Updated by GetClientFromDB()
                        , $rowId            // Updated by GetClientFromDB()
                            ) ;
    $authHistoryRow = [] ;
    $authHistoryRow['clientId'] = $clientId ;
    $authHistoryRow['clientSecret'] = $clientSecret ;
    $authHistoryRow['projectId'] = $client_json[$topKey]['project_id'] ;
    $authHistoryRow['authUri'] = $client_json[$topKey]['auth_uri'] ;
    $authHistoryRow['tokenUri'] = $client_json[$topKey]['token_uri'] ;
    $authHistoryRow['authProviderX509CertUrl'] = $client_json[$topKey]['auth_provider_x509_cert_url'] ;
    $authHistoryRow['appName'] = $appName ;
    $authHistoryRow['scopes'] = implode(',', $scopes) ;
    $authHistoryRow['accessType'] = $accessType ;
    if ((! $rowId) || $client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $accessToken = null ;
        // Refresh the token...
        if ($rowId && $client->isAccessTokenExpired() && $refreshToken) {
            $authHistoryRow['refreshToken'] = $refreshToken ;
            $client->refreshToken($refreshToken) ;
            $accessToken = $client->getAccessToken() ;
            $authHistoryRow['accessToken'] = $accessToken ;
            $expires = $accessToken['expires_in'] ;
            $authHistoryRow['expires'] = $expires ;
            }
        if ((! $accessToken) ) { // Still not able to get authorization.  Talk to user.
            printf("Authorization expired at %s\n", date('Y-m-d H:i', $expires)) ;
            //$client->setRedirectUri('http://web.lovelady.com/google-api-php-client/examples/large-file-download.php') ;
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open this link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            printf('Enter verification code: ');
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));
            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $output = print_r($accessToken, true) ;
            file_put_contents("access_token.txt", $output) ;
            }
        $accessExpiresEpoch = time() + $accessToken['expires_in'] ;
        $accessCreatedEpoch = $accessToken['created'] ;
        $this->WriteClientToDB($clientId                    // UUpdate the database
                            , $clientSecret 
                            , $accessToken['scope']
                            , $accessToken['access_token']
                            , $accessToken['token_type']
                            , $accessToken['refresh_token']
                            , $accessExpiresEpoch
                            , $accessCreatedEpoch
                                ) ;
        }
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    $authHistoryRow['accessToken'] = $accessToken ;
    $this->addClientHistory($authHistoryRow) ;
    return $client ;
    }  // End of GetAuth()
```

Comment: In your showing script, `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly]'` is not correct. I think that it is required to remove `]` of the last character. Is this related to your current issue?

Comment: @Tanaike = thanks, good eye.  I have corrected that in the script, and tested.  Alas, it did not seem to change anything.  I'll correct the question accordingly.  Thanks - it was a good find.

Comment: Thank you for replying. First, I apologize that my comment was not related to your current issue. As a simple modification, when you are using only a scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`, what result will you obtain? If this was not related to your current issue, about your script, when you retrieve the current scopes from the access token retrieved in your script, what scopes will you obtain? I guessed that the reason for your current issue might be able to be known.

Comment: has your app popped up and requested consent of the user again since you changed the scopes in your code?  please edit you question and show us an image of the consent screen and the scopes it is requesting

Comment: Just to be sure - you are actually using credentials for your Google Drive API client there, despite the method involved in fetching those being named `GetYouTubeControlParameter`, yes?

Comment: @CBroe yes, and I understand that confusion.  DriveStuff class extends YouTubeStuff, which has a not-forward-thinking method (mentioning youtube in its name).  All it does, is read a text file called (sadly) /usr/local/etc/YouTubeControl.ini) to get the parameters under which this app should run.  Other control parameters stored there are things like DB server and the like.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Thanks for the reply.  (I had a sister-in-law named Linda Layton.  Your name brought good memories.)  This is normally a batch process.  But I did run it from the web server and there was no pop-up.  You might be on to something here but I don't recall what the difference is that makes that auth page appear.  I'll investigate and update the question.

Comment: @Tanaike - thanks again, and there's no need for apologies.  Was a good find and probably would never work (with no explanation as to why).  Unfortunately, there is no improvement by requesting simply the /drive scope.  That was my original approach until I copied the scopes from that "Try It" page I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Dennis I need to see the rest of your code. Where are you authorizing this application,  how are you storing the access token and refresh token.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo  as requested, the question has been updated with this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to propose that you delete these fields from your database.

```
$accessToken      // Updated by GetClientFromDB()
, $tokenType        // Updated by GetClientFromDB()
, $refreshToken     // Updated by GetClientFromDB()
```

This should force your application to request authorization of the user again, at which time they should be shown the new scopes that your application is requesting access to and grant access. If your app is working correctly it will then store these new values into the database.

The issue you are having is that you have already requested access of the user and have stored a refresh token with the previous granted credentials.  As your app has these values already its using them to request a new access token resulting in

> Request had insufficient authentication scopes

You cant just change the scopes in your app without requesting consent from the user again.  By removing the refresh token you have stored for that user. You can then request authorization again. This time with the increase scopes.  You should then store the new refresh token in your database and it will work.

Comment: Thanks, Liinda.  Those fields are null in this record.  (There is one record for each Client ID.  This is a new project, so also a new Client ID and new Client Secret.  The (re)verification is where I have a problem for which I've opened a new issue.

Comment: Where are you calling GetAuth

Comment: The underlying problem here was that the correct authorization could not be re-requested due to a problem identified (and also solved by this answerer) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76841031/how-to-get-past-googles-oauth2-verification-for-desktop-apps .  The process needed to revisit authorization in order to use new new scopes.  Thank you, Linda.  And thank you again for the other.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have an unverified application and therefore you have scopes that you cannot use. if your app is unverified you can only use the the nonsensitive scopes and not sensitive and restricted scopes.

I believe if you follow the guide below it should work with some caveats. unless you plan to use the oauth path to authorize your application.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/api-specific-auth

for @linda

if your public application uses scopes that permit access to certain user data, it must complete a verification process. If you see unverified app on the screen when testing your application, you must submit a verification request to remove it. Find out more about unverified apps and get answers to frequently asked questions about app verification in the Help Center.

table...

The Usage column in the table above indicates the sensitivity of each scope, according to the following definitions:

Recommended / Non-sensitive—These scopes provide the smallest scope of authorization access and only requires basic app verification. For information on this requirement, see Steps to prepare for verification.

Recommended / Sensitive—These scopes provide access to specific Google User Data that's authorized by the user for your app. It requires you to go through additional app verification. For information on this requirement, see Steps for apps requesting sensitive scopes

Restricted—These scopes provide wide access to Google User Data and require you to go through a restricted scope verification process. For information on this requirement, see Google API Services: User Data Policy and Additional Requirements for Specific API Scopes. If you store restricted scope data on servers (or transmit), then you must go through a security assessment.

If your app requires access to any other Google APIs, you can add those scopes as well. For more information about Google API scopes, see Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs.

For more information about specific OAuth 2.0 scopes, see OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs.

Comment: Ah, thanks, @AlexMac - that link solves a mystery, whether the app ever works or not.  Thanks for that!.  You've correctly assessed the situation (project is unverified.)  This stuff I'm doing is all for me, and on my own YouTube and (now) Google Drive stuff, so verification seems to be overkill... but I may have to go that route or forget the idea.  The latter would be a sad shame, so I'll look into the former.  Anyway, reduction of requested scopes (to drive.file, drive.resource, drive.appdata) did not solve the problem.  May need reverification as Linda said above.  Looking into that.

Comment: @Dennis, just use the oauth and non sensitive scopes. also if you feel this is correct could you mark it as the answer?

Comment: Thanks, AlexMac.  This is an invaluable and hard-to-find link.

Comment: @AlexMac can you show me where in the documentation for verification that it states you cant use sensitive and restricted scopes for apps that have not been verified?  That's strange because I have serval that aren't verified and work fine.    They just show the unverified app screen.

Comment: it's in the link provided @linda in red alert. the right below the table.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not seeing it but where does it say you need to be verified?  [unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en)   There is nothing in verification that stops you from doing it. You just get an unverified app screen.   There's nothing that states it wont work.  My apps are still working fine.  Still not sure why you think it would throw an **Request had insufficient authentication scopes.** error either this is two different things.

Comment: he's not using oauth. why would this happen  You just get an unverified app screen

Comment: Yes he is using Oauth2 thats how you connect to google apis, you request an access token using Oauth2.  Check the last line in your anwser that you just updated.

Comment: sorry, I misspoke I meant he is not doing a redirect with uri implicit .... woooahhh what I didn't see the update. umm I would assume he have client credential grant type with a json file service worker creds or apikey and secret.

Comment: so he's scraping it. umm, well then @linda you are probably more qualified than me to answer that. I dable, however I'm not certified with gcp or anything. dennis be careful touching that config file like that too. if you aren't catching it properly you are gonna get it shared. they have packages for this stuff that make it Soo much easier. this is like 30 lines of could in my app.