# How to get past Google's OAUTH2 verification for desktop apps

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, redirect-uri

I have set up a new Project and Client ID for use by a new 'desktop' application, which now needs authorization.  Actually, the 'desktop' application is a batch process on a headless Linux server in this case.

The [OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#custom-uri-scheme) guide is Google's official instruction for obtaining the necessary Access Token and Refresh Token that such an application needs.  In step 2: send a request ... is the following text:

```
The value must exactly match one of the authorized redirect URIs for 
the OAuth 2.0 client, which you configured in your client's API Console 
Credentials page. If this value doesn't match an authorized URI, you will
get a redirect_uri_mismatch error.
```

However, when creating a Desktop client, there appears to be no place to specify a Redirect URI in the API Credentials page.  I've created a Web Client credentials on the same Google Developer's Console page, and that allows for a Redirect URL, but I don't see that at all on the Desktop client.

How can I obtain the tokens necessary to continue?  Is there some other setting that I must choose in order or the Redirect URI option to show up on Desktop Credentials, or am I misreading this, or ????

**EDIT** as requested

(... after creating a client and setting appropriate parameters...) when I execute this code...

```
$client->setRedirectUri('http://web.lovelady.com/google-api-php-client/examples/large-file-download.php')'
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
printf("Open this link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
printf('Enter verification code: ');
$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));
```

The resultant link ends with the redirect_uri_mismatch error as stated.

If I omit that first line (setRedirectUri()), then the link works and authorization takes place, but after authorization and my approval, there is a "page cannot be displayed" error

Comment: please edit your question and include your code if you are getting that message but have created a credential for a desktop app.  Then there is something wrong with your code, it should not be giving you that message for a desktop app

Comment: @DalmTo - I have made the requested edit

Comment: A desktop app in php or a console app in php?

Comment: @LindaLawtonDalmTo, I am not sure of the distinction.  Ultimately, this will be a cron job.  Google's definition for desktop seems to be the only fit.

Comment: cron job, accessing google drive api? is this a drive account you the developer control?  if so why not just use a service account and save yourself some headakes

Comment: My understanding has been that service accounts apply to corporations and quite a bit of setup interaction with Google.  I'll investigate some - been a good while - but it seems there are things preventing me from having a service account.  Hope I'm wrong.  My intent is really to simply replicate my google drive on the server in question since there doesn't seem to be a (free) option available to do this (like there is for Windoze)... plus gives me something to do in my retired state.

Comment: for Google drive service accounts are easy to use.   I would go with that.  I made this video for people like you [Should you be using a service account?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTTTtwb7x7g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my sample for Google drive with php and a desktop app.  Let me know if it helps

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

use Google\Client;
use Google\Service\Drive;

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly');
    $client->setAuthConfig('C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setRedirectUri("http://127.0.0.1");
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {

            $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token, or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the service object.
try {
    $client = getClient();
}
catch(Exception $e) {

    unlink("token.json");
    $client = getClient();
    }

$service = new Drive($client);

// Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
try{


    $optParams = array(
        'pageSize' => 10,
        'fields' => 'files(id,name,mimeType)',
        'q' => 'mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" and "root" in parents',
        'orderBy' => 'name'
    );
    $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
    $files = $results->getFiles();

    if (empty($files)) {
        print "No files found.\n";
    } else {
        print "Files:\n";
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $id = $file->id;

            printf("%s - (%s) - (%s)\n", $file->getId(), $file->getName(), $file->getMimeType());
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

## 404 error

After checking your video. I am happy to say that this is working as intended. The 404 is a result of the fact that you do not have a web server running on your machine.  but if you check the url bar you will find the code you are looking for

[image]

copy the code and place it in the app the console window and it should run.

Comment: Its working as intended check my edit.  Getting ride of the 404 is another issue.

Comment: By copying the "code" part of the URL exhibited in the "page cannot be displayed" error, I was able to gat past this.  Thank you so much, Linda, I've learned a great deal from you today.